# Tweet json - retweet or not

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

Is it possible to understand if a tweet is a retweet or not (from the json file) ?
I've found the "current_user_retweet" parameter in the json file however it always returns undefined, no mater if the tweet is a retweet or not.

Comment: What programming language / library are you using? What's your code? Can you give us an example JSON file?

Comment: Js - its twitter's json; nothing in a custom format.

Comment: We can't help unless we see the code you're using & the response you're getting.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets --- you can see the example json on the official page. As I stated earlier, it's not a custom format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the required value posting it here for future reference.

```
retweeted_status
```

This can be used to determine if a tweet (itself) is a retweet or not.